# Template doesnot exist error in Django

Tags: python, django

Am developing an angular frontend and Django backend app.I don't know where i am going wrong but Django cant seem to locate  the template and displays a template doesn't exist message.The project directory looks like this.The backend server is in the "django project" folder

[image: project directory]

base.py(settings)

```
import environ

project_root = environ.Path(__file__) - 3  
env = environ.Env(DEBUG=(bool, False),)  
CURRENT_ENV = 'dev' # 'dev' is the default environment

# read the .env file associated with the settings that're loaded
env.read_env('./mysite/{}.env'.format(CURRENT_ENV))

#Database
DATABASES = {  
'default': env.db()
}



SECRET_KEY = env('SECRET_KEY')  
DEBUG = env('DEBUG')

INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',

# Django Packages
'rest_framework',
'mysite.applications.games',


]




ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'

STATIC_URL = '/static/'  
STATICFILES_FINDERS = [  
'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
]
STATICFILES_DIRS = [  
env('FRONTEND_ROOT')
]


TEMPLATES = [  
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [env('FRONTEND_ROOT')],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
 },
]
```

Environment variables file(dev.env)

```
DATABASE_URL=sqlite:///mysite.db  
DEBUG=True
FRONTEND_ROOT= ('C:/downloads/mysite/frontend/')
SECRET_KEY= '##########################'
```

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin  
from django.conf.urls import include, url  
from mysite.applications.api.v1.routes import api_router
from django.views.generic import TemplateView



urlpatterns = [  
url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),

# Web App Entry
url(r'^$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="/app/index.html"), name='index'),
]
```

Comment: Where is your template directory ? You do not have /app/index.html file so I don't know what else to expect

Comment: the template DIRS setting points to FRONTEND_ROOT in dev.env file so FRONTEND_ROOT is the template directory.

Comment: the /app/index.html exists inside the frontend folder inside main project folder.

Comment: Have you added your app name in INSTALLED_APP section in settings.py?

Comment: You may want to try setting `APP_DIRS` to `False` inside your template setting

Comment: I added app name,also changed APP_DIRS to False.still same error.

Comment: Was following this tutorial.http://gregblogs.com/how-the-do-i-build-a-django-django-rest-framework-angular-1-1-x-and-webpack-project/

Comment: check permission of templates directory

Comment: The user has full permissions on the folder.

Comment: Please show the full error message. It will tell you the directories that Django searched for the template.

Answer (score 1):

I changed template DIRS setting to point to 'C:/downloads/mysite/frontend/' and also the template name to point to "/app/index.html".app is a folder inside frontend.